# How to insert a latex equation in Microsoft Word (2019)?

Tags: microsoft-word, latex

I tried creating an `html` file and then entering it there and grabbing the MathML and pasting it however the matrix doesn't look exactly as it does when viewed from the browser.

This is the equation:

```
$$
\begin{bmatrix}pos_x \\ pos_y\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}\frac{C_w}{V_w} \times \tau_x \\\frac{C_h}{V_h} \times \tau_y \end{bmatrix}$$
```

There must be an easier way to insert latex formulae in Microsoft Word.

Here's the difference between them:

> [image]

Comment: Try to using the build-in editor in Word: [Linear format equations using UnicodeMath and LaTeX in Word](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/linear-format-equations-using-unicodemath-and-latex-in-word-2e00618d-b1fd-49d8-8cb4-8d17f25754f8) and [Write an equation or formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/write-an-equation-or-formula-1d01cabc-ceb1-458d-bc70-7f9737722702).

Comment: @HerbGu_MSFT `\begin{bmatrix}\end{bmatrix}` does not work in the built-in equation editor.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this same problem! Solved it by adding `\left[` and '\right]` before and after the matrix command

Try this in Word and let me know if it works:

```
\left[\matrix{\frac{C_w}{V_w} \times \tau_x \\\frac{C_h}{V_h} \times \tau_y}\right]
```

Here's how it looks in Word for me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOziY.png